# Make wget download page resources on a different domain

Tags: linux, download, wget, fetch

How do you use wget to download an entire site (domain A) when its resources are on another domain, (domain B)?
I've tried:
 `wget -r --level=inf -p -k -E --domains=domainA,domainB http://www.domainA`

Comment: Wow! No one after all this time?

Comment: The reason that command doesn't work is because using `--domains` by itself doesn't turn `--span-hosts` on. Adding `--span-hosts` would've solved the problem. :|

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
wget --recursive --level=inf --page-requisites --convert-links --html-extension \
     --span-hosts=domainA,domainB url-on-domainA
```

**UPDATE:** I remember the command above worked for me in the past (that was in 2010, and I was using [GNU Tools for Windows](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)  back then); however, when I tried to use it again recently, I had to modify it as follows:

```
wget --recursive --level=inf --page-requisites --convert-links \
     --adjust-extension --span-hosts --domains=domainA,domainB domainA
```

The shorthand version for it would be: `wget -rEDpkH -l inf domainA,domainB domainA`

###### Breakdown of the flags used

- `-r` = `--recursive`
- `-l <depth>` = `--level=<depth>` (maximum recursion depth. `0` or `inf` mean unlimited recursion)
- `-E` = `--adjust-extension` (add appropriate extensions to files that have been converted to HTML or CSS)
- `-p` = `--page-requisites` (download all the files necessary to display a page (e.g., images, stylesheets)
- `-K` = `--backup-converted` (save a backup of the original file with a `.orig` extension before conversion)
- `-k` = `--convert-links` (converts links to make them suitable for local viewing)
- `-H` = `--span-hosts` (Span to any host; allow downloading from hosts different than the one in the original URL)
- `-D <domain-list>` = `--domains=<domain-list>` (Limit spanning to specified domains)
- `-np` = `--no-parent` (do not visit links that are not under the same directory as the current one)
- `-U <agent-string>` = `--user-agent=<agent-string>`

###### Reference

- GNU Wget Manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: I get: wget: --span-hosts: Invalid boolean `domainA,domainB'; use `on' or `off'.  After changing to on, it does not work.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen What I've written here worked for me. Could you provide the arguments you've used?

Comment: I don't have the exact command I ran before.  However, I have the same problem with:

`wget --recursive --level=inf --page-requisites --convert-links --html-extension --span-hosts=example.org,iana.org example.org`

I'm using GNU Wget 1.13.4 on Debian.

Comment: Try `--span-hosts --domains=example.org,iana.org` - I think `--span-hosts` needs to be a boolean, and then you use `--domains` to specify which hosts to span.

Comment: Konklone, --span-hosts is a boolean from 1.12 and later, I didn't know that. @MatthewFlaschen, I updated the answer. By the way, that will still work on 1.11 and earlier, if you're using GNU Tools for Windows.

Comment: Amazing answer, clear, with short version, everything explained, before and after, maintained. Wow! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

wget --recursive --level=inf --page-requisites --convert-links --html-extension -rH -DdomainA,domainB domainA

Comment: This partly works.  However, for some reason, it doesn't seem to work if the URL (at the end) is a redirect.  Also, it downloads links too, not just page requisites.  Also, -r and --recursive are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget --page-requisites --convert-links --adjust-extension --span-hosts --domains domainA,domainB domainA
```

You might need to ignore robots.txt (note, this may be a violation of some terms of service, and you should download the minimum required).  See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Robot-Exclusion .

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/). It has more options when crawling content on other domains than wget. Using wget with --span-hosts, --domains and --accept where insufficient for my needs but HTTrack did the job. I remember that setting limit of re-directions on other domains helped a lot.