# Download entire site for offline usage with wget (including external image servers)

Tags: command-line, download, wget

OK, so I've got wget 1.12 on Windows 7, and I can do basic downloads of it.

The site I'm trying to download: http://www.minsterfm.co.uk

and all images on it are stored externally at http://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/

How can I download the site, and the external images and possibly allow all files to keep their original extension, without converting .php files to .htm

I would appreciate any help, since I'm new to wget.

Comment: What have you managed to do this far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make wget download page resources on a different domain](http://superuser.com/questions/129085/make-wget-download-page-resources-on-a-different-domain)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an entire website?](https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website)

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) told us:

> Actually, to download a single page and all its requisites (even if
>   they exist on separate websites), and make sure the lot displays
>   properly locally, this author likes to use a few options in addition
>   to ‘-p’:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p http://the.site.com
```

You'll have to combine that with some [Recursive Download](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download) options.
You'd rather use `--wait=xx`, `--limit-rate=xxK` and `-U agent-string` to not be blacklisted by the server…

Comment: Can you maybe explain what these switches do?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [BlackWidow](http://sbl.net/) for downloadinging sites recursively on Windows.

It has the following features, but is not free:

- Scripting Engine
- User Friendly
- NetSpy (Network Spy)
- SnapShot (Web page snap shot)
- Windows Explorer like site view
- Powerful scan filters
- Expendable parser
- Wildcards & Regular Expressions